# Android Bluetooth drops connection without disconnect

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

i have a problem to read from a Bluetooth device (GPS-Logger), after ~ 30 seconds the inputstream gets no more data from the logger. 
In the timspan till the connection drops all things works perfect (read an write)

The logger bluetooth connection led gets off and i get no disconnection like ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED or ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED or something else.

The logcat brings follow error on the time when the connection drops:

```
09-08 15:24:08.219    1795-3811/com.android.bluetooth I/bt-btif﹕ btif_dm_search_services_evt:  event = 2
09-08 15:24:08.219    1795-3811/com.android.bluetooth D/bt-btif﹕ btif_dm_search_services_evt:(result=0x1, services 0x0)
09-08 15:24:08.219    1795-3811/com.android.bluetooth D/BTIF_STORAGE﹕ prop2cfg(L239): in, bd addr:11:22:33:44:74:0e, prop type:3, len:0
09-08 15:24:08.219    1795-3811/com.android.bluetooth E/BTIF_STORAGE﹕ ## ERROR : prop2cfg(L243): property type:3, len:0 is invalid##
09-08 15:24:08.219    1795-3811/com.android.bluetooth E/﹕ ### ASSERT : external/bluetooth/bluedroid/main/../btif/src/btif_dm.c line 1004 storing remote services failed (1) ###
09-08 15:24:08.219    1795-3811/com.android.bluetooth D/﹕ HAL bt_hal_cbacks->remote_device_properties_cb
09-08 15:24:08.229    1795-3811/com.android.bluetooth E/BluetoothRemoteDevices﹕ devicePropertyChangedCallback: bdDevice: 11:22:33:44:74:0E, value is empty for type: 3
```

this issue comes after this readed bytes and connection time (time between connection and last readed byte)

1. readedbytes 8783 time=29758 ms
2. readedbytes 9092 time=29663 ms
3. readedbytes 9012 time=29745 ms
4. readedbytes 8300 time=28829 ms

Can anybody help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Day's and hours i have found the solution. In the first case i had trouble with the Bluetooth device while a Test not closes the port. After Reboot and re-paired the device it works. Another Android device with Android 4.1.2 drops the connection after 2 seconds ;-( ahhhhhh.. the solution ist don't call the the orginal

> createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord

this not work for special Spp Devices the solution is:

```
      try {
            _logger.log(Level.FINEST,"createInsecureRfcommSocket by reflection");
            fSocket = (BluetoothSocket)fDevice.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE}).invoke(fDevice, new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1)});
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            fSocket = null;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            fSocket = null;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            fSocket = null;
        }


        if (fSocket == null) {
            _logger.log(Level.FINEST,"Connect over createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord");
            fSocket = fDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        }
```

terrible!!! I found this in a lucky break. I hope this helps anyone with the same problems.

Matze

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and for me, adding a ***device.getUuids()*** method instead of trying to connect with the standard UUID (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB) fixed it. But I'm not quite sure why that is...

Below follows my code adapted from Google's Bluetooth Chat example.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private String mSocketType;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID_SPP);
                } else {
                    UUID mUUID= device.getUuids()[0].getUuid();
                    tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
            }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        mState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    }
```